# I am trying to restrict functionality of export data in tree view for some users in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-13

It says that the button name 'export_xlsx' is not located in parent view but I have looked up the external ID for the web module and this is the only ID I got. Can someone help? Also guide me how I add the admin to still have access to it
Code:

```
<record id="export_button_hide" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">export.hide.form.inherit</field>
      <field name="model">base</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.module_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='export_xlsx']" position="attributes">
          <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

**Error:**
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 669, in apply_inheritance_specs
source = apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree,
File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/template_inheritance.py", line 229, in apply_inheritance_specs
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Element '' cannot be located in parent view

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4146, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4060, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 475, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-96>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/home/faiza/Desktop/Faiza-office/design-creative-bahrian/smile_audit/models/base.py", line 67, in create
    return super(Base, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3821, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1122, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 493, in write
    res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/home/faiza/Desktop/Faiza-office/design-creative-bahrian/smile_audit/models/base.py", line 105, in write
    return super(Base, self).write(vals)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3610, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 1201, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 387, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 745, in read_combined
    arch = self.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, root.id, self.model)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 694, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = self.apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree, view_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 673, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(str(e), inherit_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 614, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Element '<xpath expr="//button[@name='export_xlsx']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `export.hide.form.inherit`
[view_id: 980, xml_id: n/a, model: base, parent_id: 93]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1330, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1318, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 634, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 225, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 736, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 803, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 715, in parse
    pycompat.reraise(
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 13, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4146, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4060, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 475, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-96>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/home/faiza/Desktop/Faiza-office/design-creative-bahrian/smile_audit/models/base.py", line 67, in create
    return super(Base, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3821, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1122, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 493, in write
    res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/home/faiza/Desktop/Faiza-office/design-creative-bahrian/smile_audit/models/base.py", line 105, in write
    return super(Base, self).write(vals)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3610, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 1201, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 387, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 745, in read_combined
    arch = self.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, root.id, self.model)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 694, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = self.apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree, view_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 673, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(str(e), inherit_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 614, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Element '<xpath expr="//button[@name='export_xlsx']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `export.hide.form.inherit`
[view_id: 980, xml_id: n/a, model: base, parent_id: 93]" while parsing /home/faiza/Desktop/Faiza-office/design-creative-bahrian/spreadsheet/views/remove_export.xml:3, near
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="export_button_hide" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">export.hide.form.inherit</field>
      <field name="model">base</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.module_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='export_xlsx']" position="attributes">
          <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>

<!--    <template id="assets_backend" name="remove_export_option_view_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">-->
<!--      <xpath expr="template/ListView.buttons/o_list_buttons/export_xlsx" position="replace">-->
<!--        <script type="text/xml" src="web/static/src/xml/base.xml" groups="base.group_system"></script>-->
<!--      </xpath>-->
<!--    </template>-->

  </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
  <data>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="remove_export_option_view assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/remove_export_option/static/src/js/remove_export_option.js"></script>
      </xpath>
    </template>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

Create JS file with name:remove_export_option.js "

```
odoo.define('remove_export_option.remove_export_option', function (require) {
"use strict";

var Sidebar = require('web.Sidebar');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var _lt = core._lt;
    Sidebar.include({
        start: function () {
            var self = this;
            var def;
            var export_label = _t("Export");
            def = this.getSession().user_has_group('base.user_admin').then(function(has_group) {
                if (!has_group)
                {
                    self.items['other'] = $.grep(self.items['other'], function(i){
                        return i && i.label && i.label != export_label;
                    });
                }
            });
            return Promise.resolve(def).then(this._super.bind(this));
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this piece of code, let me try it again. Also I can't find data_export.css

Comment: You can use this too: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/remove_export_option/ and in your case it's not data_export.css please check my answer.

Comment: Okay understood, I am trying your solution. Also I have downloaded this module and tried but it does not work for me. Just shows the option to check the "export data" in user's groups  but when I test it it does not work.

Comment: I am guessing that the 3rd last line of code is also as : widgets/data_export.js ??

Comment: ya sorry , lemme update my answer. Also that module works perfectly fine for me. Users having Export Visible check box checked will be able to see the export and rest will not.

Comment: Error:

I am getting this error as I login from the different user to check whether export option is removed for him or not. Can you help?
Traceback:
Error: curView is undefined
_executeWindowAction/</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_act_window.js:307:38

Comment: I have tried everything you have mentioned in your answer there is no error but still the export option is there for other user do I need to update some setting?

Comment: Use that module which I've shared with you then try it by giving access to group Export Visible, by doing this users with Export Visible access will be able to see the export button or you can use that module and add your group i.e base.user_admin in js. Both will work as it is working perfect for me.

Comment: You're doing something wrong keep digging above code and module work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery=".o_list_export_xlsx" t-operation="replace"/>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Wrong approach as this will replace export button for all the users.